# Get rid of extra comma added in the csv while updating column values

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a code to update particular column values in the CSV through pandas data frame. After the code execution, what I see is an extra column added at the start. This comma causes a misalignment of my CSV structure. For e.g. I updated age column value in the CSV as 30 which was 26 earlier for each of the rows, what I see in the notepad is as follows.

```
,Name,Age,Gender
Pratik,30,Male
Sarvesh,30,Male
```

If you see at the start of the Header column Name, an extra column is been added. How to remove or restrict that? Below is my code.

```
df = pd.read_csv("{}/output/Float_Ingestion_Expected_Output_files/{}/{}.csv".format(str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name,header=None))
    #for x in df:
    df['age'] = '2323323232444'
  
    df.to_csv("{}/output/Float_Ingestion_Expected_Output_files/{}/{}.csv".format(str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name, index=False))
    print(df)
```

Comment: As much as there might be a solution for the problem, perhaps the best thing would be to fix how the csv is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fixing the original CSV file is not an option, relabel the columns and drop the last one:

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, df.columns[1:]))).dropna(axis=1)
#      Name  Age Gender
#0   Pratik   30   Male
#1  Sarvesh   30   Male
```